# searching in LinkedIn for information in a specific section

Tags: search, linkedin-api

Is there any method that we can search in LinkedIn based on specific section of the profile, for example finding a keyword in the experience section. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless that information is public on their profile then no. If you type keywords into the search bar such as companies then people who work at those companies will show up. I would assume that if you wanted to search for twitter handles that information would need to be in their bio

Comment: I search for a twitter user names of one person in the search filed but there is no result although he has written his user name in his "Contact info" section.